# Communicate with a microcontroller over ethernet

Tags: webserver, telnet, avr, ethernet

I am planning to make some microcontroller boards which would do miscellaneous tasks. For example measuring analog voltages or controlling other instruments. Each board needs to be controlled/downloaded it's data from one place. For that purpose I would use an ethernet interface and do the comnunication over that. So my question is: which would be the most suitable method of achieving that. My ideas are: run a webserver on each module and communicate with POST/GET, or run a telnet server on boards and communicate with a telnet client. The security and speed/latency is not an concern but the data integrity is.
I don't need a html based gui for modules because I will implement an application which will communicate wizh the modules periodically, gets the data from them and stores in a database. And the database is what I will use later, for examining the data for example. 
An other example:
I have a board which measures measures temperature. There is a server on the board itself run by the mcu. It is connected to a router via the ENC chip. I have my pc also connected to that router. I have an application which connects to the server run by the Atmega328 and collects the data then stores to a database. It repeats this let's say in every hour. I would use an Atmega328 and an ENC28J60 ethernet interface chip. What do you recommend?

Comment: Data integrity should also not be an issue as long as you use a tcp based protocol. But I see two aspects that might be worth considering: potential firewalls are probably more generous with an http based protocol (read: using that from a public WLAN for example) but http has a much higher latency due to its request based approach compared to a persistent socket approach. You could use websockets for that, but things get more complex compared to a directly socket based protocol. But then again: using http you can simply create your GUI based on html, which is easy and flexible.

Comment: The latency is not a problem. The html gui is not required because I will manage with my own application. I want to be as simple as possible in the mcu side because I have limited space and I neet that for other things.

Comment: So this communication would be used in most cases for data logging.

Comment: I see no further restrictions then, the only point unclear to me now: http requires you to poll on a regular base, whilst a plain socket allows the activity to be pushed, since the socket is persistent and the server can simply write into it. Depends on what you prefer on the client side.

Comment: I edited my original question.

Comment: Given that you plan to poll on a periodic base I would clearly opt for http as protocol. It is wide spread, reliable, robust, easy to log (thus debug) and you can expect little issues with network topology. The http status codes come in handy in case of problems, server implementation exist in all flavors as do server side handler options (scripting languages).

Comment: So you're saying that the most suitable way is to implement a http server which is run by the atmwga328 and communicate with the server from my pc using post/get methods?

Comment: Yes, though your comment is a bit miss leading. So to have this really clear: server running on the board, client running on your PC making `HTTP GET` requests to the boards server.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I need the simplest and cheapest(in terms of size) method because I have limited resources in Atmega328. So if its simpler to implement, a telnet server, or something similar would be just fine.

Comment: Then probably you won't go with a ready-to-use http server which is very convenient, but with a minimal implementation which only implements exactly what you need, so only `GET` requests, no logging, no fancy error handling. There are libraries for such stuff.

Comment: I know. I did a research about that. I just wanted to ask other people to see how they did. Or to find out if there are other approaches.

Comment: I would use http protocol for interactive exchange with the MCU ... if it is mostly about downloading data fromthe MCU (measurement data etc.) I'd rather go for (T)FTP.